# 2012 AIME II #8: Complex Problem

Tags: contest-math

[image: Problem]

When attempting to solve this question, I multiplied the equations to extrapolate the zw. Once I did this though, I ran into some confusion. Am I allowed to use the quadratic formula here? If I am, can someone demonstrate how to solve the part under the radical?

Comment: Yes you are. This is an example of why knowing the proof of something allows you to decide whether you can apply it in slightly different conditions. Note that any non-zero complex number has two square roots.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I do know the quadratic formula proof -derived using completing the square version at least; I still don't understand how to clear the radical though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you doing in the right way.

Given $z+\frac{20i}{w}=5+i$ and $w+\frac{12i}{z}=-4+10i$
$$zw+32i-\frac{240}{zw}=-30+46i$$
$$(zw)^2+(30-14i)zw-240=0$$

Now use the quadratic formula $x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ and we get

Here $a=1,b=(30-14i),c=-240$
$$=\frac{-(30-14i)\pm \sqrt{(30-14i)^2-4(1)(-240)}}{2(1)}$$
$$=\frac{-2(15-7i)\pm \sqrt{(2(15-7i))^2-4(1)(-240)}}{2(1)}$$
$$=\frac{-2(15-7i)\pm 2\sqrt{(15-7i)^2+240}}{2(1)}$$
Note that $\sqrt{(15-7i)^2+240}=\sqrt{416-210i}=\sqrt{(5i-21)^2}=5i-21$
$$7i-15\pm\sqrt{(15-7i)^2+240}=6+2i,12i-36$$

Now
$$|zw|^2=6^2+2^2=40$$ and 
$$|zw|^2=12^2+36^2>40$$
So, the smallest value is $40$

Comment: How did you simplify the radical though?

Comment: I edited it now, see the calculations

Comment: Sorry for being confusing, I meant how did you go from (15-7i^20+240 to the stuff on the right? I tried using symbolab, but I keep getting 416-210i.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to understand how you are able to even bring it in that form. Can you plz help? Thanks for the solution btw.

Comment: I added the explanation, see the edit

Comment: Thank you so much!